# UIBarButtonItemStyle Bordered, Done, Plain what is the difference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

`UIBarButtonItemStyle` can be:

- Bordered
- Done
- Plain

**Even reading the documentation I do not know what is the difference and when do I use which?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can read [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonItemStyle) then you can find its answer. As par doc this Border,plain and Done is a **Specifies the style of a item**.

[image]

- **Plain (UIBarButtonItemStylePlain)**

  Glows when tapped. The default item style.
- **Border (UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered)**

  A simple button style with a border.
- **Done (UIBarButtonItemStyleDone)**

  The style for a done button—for example, a button that completes some task and returns to the previous view.

For testing you can create a demo project in Xcode and set different different style and you can understand the difference.